# Install fancyimpute on jupyter

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, fancyimpute

I know this have been asked before. 
But, a lot of version specific (platform, windows, python, annaconda, vc..) are driving me crazy.

Been trying pip install from cmd, conda install from cmd. !pip install from jupyter. updating vc. isntalling ecos and w/e they are saying im missing.

update - pip install success. and now when i do pip install i get "Requirement already satisfied" for all.

this is the log of the error
[log error](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=61948968657617672891)

This is the Error im getting while trying to import

```
You can find the C code in this temporary file: c:\users\koren\appdata\local\temp\theano_compilation_error_kggj9k
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-af7661c2d4f1> in <module>()
      7 import warnings
      8 import math
----> 9 from fancyimpute import KNN
     10 warnings.simplefilter('ignore', np.RankWarning)
     11 pd.options.display.max_rows = 999

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\fancyimpute\__init__.py in <module>()
      5 from .bayesian_ridge_regression import BayesianRidgeRegression
      6 from .mice import MICE
----> 7 from .matrix_factorization import MatrixFactorization
      8 from .iterative_svd import IterativeSVD
      9 from .simple_fill import SimpleFill

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\fancyimpute\matrix_factorization.py in <module>()
     14 
     15 import climate
---> 16 import downhill
     17 import numpy as np
     18 import theano

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\downhill\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .adaptive import *
      2 from .base import build, Optimizer
      3 from .dataset import Dataset
      4 from .first_order import *
      5 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\downhill\adaptive.py in <module>()
      5 
      6 import numpy as np
----> 7 import theano
      8 import theano.tensor as TT
      9 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.pyc in <module>()
    108     object2, utils)
    109 
--> 110 from theano.compile import (
    111     SymbolicInput, In,
    112     SymbolicOutput, Out,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py in <module>()
     10 from theano.compile.function_module import *
     11 
---> 12 from theano.compile.mode import *
     13 
     14 from theano.compile.io import *

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py in <module>()
      9 import theano
     10 from theano import gof
---> 11 import theano.gof.vm
     12 from theano import config
     13 from six import string_types

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py in <module>()
    671     if not theano.config.cxx:
    672         raise theano.gof.cmodule.MissingGXX('lazylinker will not be imported if theano.config.cxx is not set.')
--> 673     from . import lazylinker_c
    674 
    675     class CVM(lazylinker_c.CLazyLinker, VM):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py in <module>()
    125             args = cmodule.GCC_compiler.compile_args()
    126             cmodule.GCC_compiler.compile_str(dirname, code, location=loc,
--> 127                                              preargs=args)
    128             # Save version into the __init__.py file.
    129             init_py = os.path.join(loc, '__init__.py')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.pyc in compile_str(module_name, src_code, location, include_dirs, lib_dirs, libs, preargs, py_module, hide_symbols)
   2354             # difficult to read.
   2355             raise Exception('Compilation failed (return status=%s): %s' %
-> 2356                             (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
   2357         elif config.cmodule.compilation_warning and compile_stderr:
   2358             # Print errors just below the command line.

. collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_42_Stepping_7_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-32/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:976: undefined reference to `_imp___Py_TrueStruct'Error'ndefined references to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct' followow
```

Comment: some progress.nos i get this error while tring to import library